# Hook an static linked ELF binary

Tags: c++, static, hook, elf, ld-preload

I have an application that have openssl statically linked elf binary and i'm about to hook some of it's openssl function to get pre-master key thus allow me to decrypt the connections using wireshark.

I'm aware and know how to LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH hooking shared library, but this is statically linked binary.

Fortunately, the static elf didn't strip their debug symbol, so all named function i'm to hooking to are identified.

How do I have todo to hook this statically linked elf ?

**ELF Header:**

```
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x80ceae0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          3285112 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         28
  Section header string table index: 27
```

**Program Headers:**

```
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Entry point 0x80ceae0                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52                                                                                                                                                                                           

Program Headers:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align                                                                                                                                                                    
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00100 0x00100 R E 0x4                                                                                                                                                                      
  INTERP         0x000134 0x08048134 0x08048134 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1                                                                                                                                                                      
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]                                                                                                                                                                                   
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x309507 0x309507 R E 0x1000                                                                                                                                                                 
  LOAD           0x309520 0x08352520 0x08352520 0x13168 0x29934 RW  0x1000                                                                                                                                                                   
  DYNAMIC        0x31c0fc 0x083650fc 0x083650fc 0x00100 0x00100 RW  0x4                                                                                                                                                                      
  NOTE           0x000148 0x08048148 0x08048148 0x00020 0x00020 R   0x4                                                                                                                                                                      
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x2ccc30 0x08314c30 0x08314c30 0x0a06c 0x0a06c R   0x4                                                                                                                                                                      
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RWE 0x4

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rel.dyn .rel.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame .gcc_except_table 
   03     .data .dynamic .ctors .dtors .jcr .got .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07
```

**Symbol Table:**

```
  ...
  8627: 081ddbb0   408 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_free
  8629: 081de360   190 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_copy_session_id
  8665: 081deba0   148 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_get_shared_ciphers
  8848: 081df2f0    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_set_default_passw
  8927: 081e03a0    42 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_set_cert_store
  8996: 081de2d0    94 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_get_peer_certificate
  9079: 081e0250    14 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_get_verify_result
  9130: 081e52e0   269 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_use_RSAPrivateKey
  9193: 081e0f70    20 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_SESSION_get_ex_data
  9266: 081e0230    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_set_verify_result
  9305: 081df350    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth
  9394: 081de230    14 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_get_verify_depth
  9409: 081e1840    36 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_remove_session
  9590: 081e3390    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_rstate_string
  9655: 081df8c0   122 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_set_ssl_method
  9662: 081e0360    20 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_get_ex_data
  9691: 081de330    38 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_get_peer_cert_chain
  9696: 081e0d20    20 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_lis
  9798: 081e0d50    68 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_get_client_CA_list
  9810: 081de6f0   138 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 SSL_write
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use GDB with a breakpoint command (perhaps involving Python scripting), or Systemtap.  There is no direct way to interpose functions which are not listed in the `.dynsym` section (which is of course missing due to static linking).

Comment: is it possible to build our own `.dynsym` and copy the segment into the binary with `objcopy` based on existing symbol table ?

Comment: You would have relink the application dynamically. I assume that you do no have the sources (or object files) available, so that's not an option. Systemtap may still work in this situation.